# Why iAd doesn't display ads?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I recently launch a n iPhone app, with iAd on it. I simply dragged a banner to the app, which should be supposed to work. However, after several hours of app being in app store, the app cannot display adds on my testing iPhone. Anyone encounter similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that you have properly filled up the Bank and Taxation details and also agreed to Paid application license of the Developer account.

These are the common issues with iAd not displaying on app store application.